# SQL select all records only if all amount is not zero for a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

| EMPLOYEE | AMOUNT | PAYCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 0 | SALARY |
| 121 | 5 | ALLOWANCE |
| 122 | 0 | SALARY |
| 122 | 0 | ALLOWANCE |
| 123 | 5 | SALARY |
| 123 | -5 | ALLOWANCE |

I am stuck with this problem. I want to select only the employees where all amounts are zero(0). Tried using **HAVING SUM(Amount)<>0** but will need to also select records like the employee 123 above. The output must be:

| EMPLOYEE | AMOUNT | PAYCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 0 | SALARY |
| 121 | 5 | ALLOWANCE |
| 123 | 5 | SALARY |
| 123 | -5 | ALLOWANCE |

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track.  Consider this version:

```sql
SELECT EMPLOYEE
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE
HAVING SUM(AMOUNT <> 0) = 0;
```

You could also phrase this by saying that the zero amount count is equal to the total count:

```sql
SELECT EMPLOYEE
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE
HAVING SUM(AMOUNT = 0) = COUNT(*);
```

Comment: Feel silly for saying this, but I never realized `SUM(AMOUNT = 0)` behaves like a CASE.  Learn something new every day.  Does that style/syntax have a name?

Comment: @SOS You can only do this on MySQL and a few other databases.  It is called summing a boolean expression.  The version you were likely using, with a `CASE` expression, achieves the same thing, but is more verbose.  But, your version would work on basically every SQL database, while my answer is tailored for MySQL.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Still pretty cool. I haven't used MySQL as much, so never learned about that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`. First, I have selected all the employees for which there is at least a single row in which amount is not 0. Then with `exists()` I have selected all the rows for those employees.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table employee_payment(EMPLOYEE int, AMOUNT int, PAYCODE varchar(50));
 insert into employee_payment values(121,   0,  'SALARY');
 insert into employee_payment values(121,   5,  'ALLOWANCE');
 insert into employee_payment values(122,   0,  'SALARY');
 insert into employee_payment values(122,   0,  'ALLOWANCE');
 insert into employee_payment values(123,   5,  'SALARY');
 insert into employee_payment values(123,   -5, 'ALLOWANCE');
```

Query:

```
 select * from employee_payment e
 where exists 
 (
   SELECT 1
   FROM employee_payment ep
   where ep.amount<>0 and e.EMPLOYEE=ep.EMPLOYEE
 )
```

Output:

| EMPLOYEE | AMOUNT | PAYCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 0 | SALARY |
| 121 | 5 | ALLOWANCE |
| 123 | 5 | SALARY |
| 123 | -5 | ALLOWANCE |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=deb2ad7e2b6668242a31a2aa2bcdb262)*

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional SUM() and window functions to get the total non-zero amounts per employee. Then exclude ones with all 0's

```
 WITH cte AS (
   SELECT * 
          , SUM(CASE WHEN Amount > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee) AS TotalNonZero
   FROM   Employee
 )
 SELECT Employee, Amount, PayCode
 FROM   cte
 WHERE  TotalNonZero > 0
 ;
```

**Results:**

| Employee | Amount | PayCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 0 | SALARY |
| 121 | 5 | ALLOWANCE |
| 123 | 5 | SALARY |
| 123 | -5 | ALLOWANCE |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=abd95bcc4264f5787c2e494b071c9bcc)*